# How do I identify the correct bits of the HTML to scrape episode data with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to improve my Python by playing around with `Beautifulsoup` and the `requests` modules. I've done a few of the tutorials and have successfully scraped data from various place, but can't manage to get this one working. I know there is a ready made product `imdb` offer for accessing data, but I like using the site to practise Python.

I'm trying to scrape the titles of each of the episodes on [this page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094525/episodes?season=5&ref_=tt_eps_sn_5), but my code is just giving me an empty list.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094525/episodes?season=5&ref_=tt_eps_sn_5'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                         '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
pageTree = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup) #testing its working
print(soup.title.string)

episodes_list = []

episodes = soup.find_all("a", class_="title")

for episode in episodes:
    episodeName = episodes.find("a").get_text()
    episodes_list.append(episodeName)
print(episodes_list)
```

Pointers would be greatly appreciated, I know the issue is with the `episodes` variable, but trial and error has not given me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for elements with `class` = `title`, but if you look at the HTML, the `a` elements you're looking for don't have a `class` attribute. For example:

```
<a href="/title/tt0676164/"
title="The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb" itemprop="url">...</a>
```

There is a `title` attribute, but not `class` attribute. Reading through the [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), it looks like you can use a regular expression has an attribute filter, so we can probably do something like this:

```
episodes = soup.find_all("a", title=re.compile('.'))
```

That finds everything with a non-empty `title` attribute, which seems to be what you want:

```
>>> episodes = soup.find_all("a", title=re.compile('.'))
>>> [x.get('title') for x in episodes]
['The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb', 'The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb', 
'The Underdog', 'The Underdog', 'The Yellow Iris', 'The Yellow Iris', 
'The Case of the Missing Will', 'The Case of the Missing Will', 
'The Adventure of the Italian Nobleman', 'The Adventure of the Italian Nobleman', 
'The Chocolate Box', 'The Chocolate Box', "Dead Man's Mirror", 
"Dead Man's Mirror", 'Jewel Robbery at the Grand Metropolitan', 
'Jewel Robbery at the Grand Metropolitan', 'Share on Facebook', 
'Share on Twitter', 'Share the page', 'Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Twitch',
'Twitter', 'YouTube']
```

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate the explanation and response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It will select only the title of the series and put it into the episode list.

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094525/episodes?season=5&ref_=tt_eps_sn_5'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                         '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
pageTree = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')



episodes_list = []

episodes = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "info"})

# Iterate over results and print
for episode in episodes:
    episodes_list.append(episode.a.text)


print(episodes_list)
```

The output will look like this:

> ['The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb', 'The Underdog', 'The Yellow Iris', 'The Case of the Missing Will', 'The Adventure of the Italian Nobleman', 'The Chocolate Box', "Dead Man's Mirror", 'Jewel Robbery at the Grand Metropolitan']

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate the reply. Could you quickly explain how only the title is collected from the info, please? Is it because it is the only text available in the info class?

Comment: So  the findall function in this instance finds all of the divs in the html code that contain the class 'info'. So effectively it finds a list of all the 'info' divs. Within each of the divs there is a link denoted by 'a'  which contains text which in the case is the title of each episode.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand, one more question, sorry. 
Does the 'a' in '''(episode.*a*.text)''' find the link denoted by 'a' which contains the episode text?

Comment: It really helps if you look at the html for example in chrome click on the piece of text  that you want to scrape and select inspect , this will bring up the selected piece of html . In this case it will show the <a> tag  which is a html hyperlink.  So in the above example the a tag finds the hyperlink associated the particular episode.

Comment: Understood on that part, thanks, just unclear on what the “a” in the append(episode.a.text) was for. 

Thanks for replying I really appreciate it.